# What is the preposition right here? He reached ___ his house at night

Tags: prepositions

I am not sure what preposition I should put here. I am thinking of maybe at/to but i am not sure.

> He reached ___ his house at night

Comment: No preposition I can think of would form anything that really makes sense. What are you trying to express?

Comment: *reach* is a transitive verb; i.e. it takes a **direct** object. Perhaps you're confusing it with *arrive*?

Comment: I dont know :p i have this question at my homework

Comment: I’ve voted to close this question for being unclear because on EL&U, you’re expected to provide the intended meaning when asking for this type of word request. Otherwise one could justify using just about any preposition or even no preposition. E.g. *at, for, around, inside, outside*, etc.

Comment: Looks like your teacher botched the question.

Answer (score 1):

According to Collins Dictionary: 
'To reach' is a transitive verb.  It is used with the direct object. So there is no preposition.
'To reach' means
to get to or get as far as in moving, going, traveling, etc.: The boat reached the shore.

Comment: No, that's wrong. *Reach* certainly *can* take prepositions. *Reach around*, *reach for*, and so on. But while *he reached* ***around*** *his house at night* is syntactical, it has little meaning.

Comment: @JasonBassford Depends how long his arms are (or how small his house).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet What if he is a hermit crab?